# Is there a simple way to extract variable values given a formatted f-string and the original template?

Tags: python, string, f-string

Assume we have an f-string-style template:

`"{kid} ate {number} {fruit}"`

and a formatted version of that:

`"Jack ate 42 apples"`

How could I, very generally, extract `"Jack"`, `"42"`, and `"apples"` from this string based on the fact that they match `kid`, `number`, and `fruit` respectively? Assume that the f-string could be anything and contain any number of simple string or integer variables (no formatting instructions), and that the string for extraction has already been generated from that f-string, and so matches it perfectly. This also means that I can't use regex rather than f-string-style formatting, unless there's a way to generate a regex *based* on the f-string.

I already have something that works for my case, but it's not general, and feels a little hacky to me. I feel like there must be something simpler that I just can't find the right words to google:

```
template = "{kid} ate {number} {fruit}"
example = "Jack ate 42 apples"
extracted = {"kid": "", "number": "", "fruit": ""}
for variable in extracted.keys():
    extracted[variable] = example
    for chunk in template.split(f"{{variable}}"):
        extracted[variable] = extracted[variable].replace(chunk, "")
```

If it's not possible to get both more simple and more general, then more simple with the same level of generality would be great too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex and match group like this:

- To create a group with name: `(?'name')`
- Match any characters unlimited times: `.+`

```py
import re

pattern = r"(?P<name>.+) ate (?P<number>.+) (?P<fruit>.+)"

text = "John ate 3 apples"
match = re.match(pattern, text)

if match:
    name = match.group('name')
    number = match.group('number')
    fruit = match.group('fruit')
    print(f"{name} ate {number} {fruit}")
else:
    print("Pattern not found in the text.")
```

I hope this is what you want

Comment: To make this work I need to add a line that generates the regex from the original pattern, but that's simple, e.g. pattern = pattern.replace("{", "(?P<").replace("}", ">.+)"). But it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using external packages, there's the excellent [`parse`](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse):

```py
import parse
  
template = "{kid} ate {number} {fruit}"  
example = template.format(kid="Jack", number=42, fruit="apples")
  
extracted = parse.parse(template, example).named
print(extracted)
```